# What are the alternatives for prefixed indexes in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, index, feature-comparison

You can create an index and define prefix length, so the index will store only first starting symbols from each of column value. It looks like this in MySQL:

```
CREATE INDEX table_idx ON emp(last_name(8));
```

Are there an alternative how to do that in Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an index on an expression (which you cannot do in MySQL):

```
CREATE INDEX table_idx ON emp(substr(last_name,1,8));
```

But that won't help anything unless you also use that expression in the where clause, e.g.

```
where substr(last_name,1,8) = 'foobar'
```

What exactly is the usage of an index in MySQL that doesn't index the whole value?

Comment: There might be cases where we use varchar2 type columns with descriptions. If descriptions are long and if each description has some more or lest unique start then it would be convenient to have smaller index that might work faster than full-length index.

Comment: An example of a useful index that doesn't index the whole value: Suppose 'start dates' are stored as text in the form 'yyyy-mm-dd', but you only want to extract annual recurrences (anniversaries or billing points etc) based on 'mm' matching the current month, or range of months in Q3 say.

Answer (score 0):

I found there are special "Oracle Text" indexes that improve performance for wildcard queries. Such index construction requires a little bit more work but still is a way how to create prefix indexes:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm#i1007102

Comment: That's pretty radically different from prefix indexes.

Comment: @Mat Why different? Both ways we try to get better performance for wildcard queries. The only thing I not sure in is index size.

Comment: Index size, how you maintain them (depending on type, there are manual steps, not always up-to-date), how you must write your queries to actually use them, ... Full-text search indexes aren't ordinary database indexes. If what you need in MySQL is a prefix index and not a full-text search index, the equivalent in Oracle is what a_horse_with_no_name posted above, not Oracle Text.